# What's wrong using the mailchimp_transactional client?

Tags: python, mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I getting this error :

```
  File "/Users/hernan0216/services/project/services/email.py", line 84, in _send_template
    result = self.client.messages.send_template(**data)
  File "/Users/hernan0216/services/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mailchimp_transactional/api/messages_api.py", line 422, in send_template
    (data) = self.send_template_with_http_info(body, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/Users/hernan0216/services/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mailchimp_transactional/api/messages_api.py", line 438, in send_template_with_http_info
    " to method send_template" % key
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name' to method send_template
```

data should be something like this

```
data = {'template_name': 'name_template', 'template_content': [], 'message': {'from_email': 'noreply@ex.com', 'from_name': 'Ex', 'subject': "some string", 'to': [{'email': 'ex@example.com', 'name': 'Example', 'type': 'to'}], 'global_merge_vars': [{'name': 'STUDENT_NAME', 'content': 'Example Name'}]}}
```

Like is specified on the mailchimp api [docs](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-using-message-template/) for the send_template method

In the  mailchimp_transactional client I found this [code](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-transactional-python/blob/master/mailchimp_transactional/api/messages_api.py#L431), that say than accepts only "body" as keyword argument, should I open an issue? Should be on the client, docs or api ?? Maybe I'm missing something, if that the case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as a regular `body` argument instead of keyword arguments - without `**`. The keyword params syntax had to be used in legacy Mandrill Python API, the Mailchimp Transactional API does not require it.

```
result = self.client.messages.send_template(data)
```